# Symfony/PHPUnit mock services

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm writing functional tests for Symfony w/ PHPUnit, and my mocks aren't working. It's possible I misunderstood how they work though.

In my unit test's `setUp()` method I have this code:

```
...
// Create a stub
$stub = $this->getMockBuilder('\\ApiBundle\\Util\\WordPressBridge')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

// Configure the stub.
$user = new WordPressUser();
$user->setUsername('dummy');
$stub->expects($this->any())
     ->method('checkCredentials')
     ->will($this->returnValue(true));
$stub->expects($this->any())
     ->method('getUser')
     ->will($this->returnValue($user));
...
```

In my Symfony application, I have a service defined:

```
services:
    api.wp_bridge:
        class: ApiBundle\Util\WordPressBridge
        arguments: [@service_container]
```

It's my understanding that the mock should be replace the real `WordPressBridge`, but that isn't what's happening. My original is still being used. Am I missing something?

Comment: “Functional unit tests” is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's my understanding that the mock should be replace the real WordPressBridge, but that isn't what's happening. My original is still being used. Am I missing something?

Basically you have to replace your service somehow in the Symfony Container.

If you doing "functional testing" then probably you should create test "dummy" service for **"test"** env which will overwrote original one. You can do something like that:

in **src/YourBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    api.wp_bridge:
        class: %api.wp_bridge.class%
        arguments: [@service_container]
```

in **app/config/config.yml**

```
parameters:
    api.wp_bridge.class: "ApiBundle\Util\WordPressBridge"
```

in **app/config/config_test.yml**

```
parameters:
    api.wp_bridge.class: "ApiBundle\Util\TestWordPressBridge"
```

Then functional test will use "ApiBundle\Util\TestWordPressBridge" - cause it is executed in **"test"** env.

You can try to mock container and pass it to test kernel but this can be painfull without some other mocking lib (in pure PHPUnit).

Personally I am using [phpspec2](http://phpspec.net/) for "unit" testing where mocking is just easy :) and for some "acceptance criteria" stuff I am using [behat](http://behat.org/) and [mink](http://mink.behat.org/)